# Login As User from Frontend

Tags: login, frontend

In the CP there is a button which allows you to log in as a specific user. Can this be called from the Frontend/plugin or is it strictly a CP function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call it from the front-end, but it requires the currently logged in user to be an administrator.

Just point the form's hidden action input to `users/impersonate` and have it submit a 'userId' input of the person you want to log in as.

Comment: Hi Brad, But do you have to be admin? Is there a way to use this feature for non-root admins? I want them to login as another user, but when I give them all user altering rights, the dropdown with the cog doesn't show me the option to take over another account. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to be an admin to impersonate another user.